# Data Labeling: Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

I have to label my data row wise in `csv` considering two parameters :

```
1. VE in range 0.9 to 1.3 or 0
2. Calculated load value in range 20 to 50
```

I have to label these as `1` and others as `-1` by adding another column.

I have tried `numpy.where` and `pandas.where` but it gives an error saying `series is ambiguous`.

Also how can I use python preprocessing for the same?

[Snippet of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBWvF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np

In [335]: df
Out[335]: 
     VE  load_value
0  0.59        31.0
1  0.66        26.7
2  0.57        47.5
3  0.54        70.2
4  0.59        45.1
5  0.85        31.0
6  0.94        33.7
7  0.97        32.9
8  0.96        32.9

In [336]: df['label'] = np.where((df.VE <1.3) & (df.VE >= 0.9) & (df.load_value >=20) & (df.load_value <50), 1, -1)

In [337]: df
Out[337]: 
     VE  load_value  label
0  0.59        31.0     -1
1  0.66        26.7     -1
2  0.57        47.5     -1
3  0.54        70.2     -1
4  0.59        45.1     -1
5  0.85        31.0     -1
6  0.94        33.7      1
7  0.97        32.9      1
8  0.96        32.9      1
```